# How to remove Angular material data table sorting direction empty state?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

Angular material sortion direction giving 3 states asc , desc, empty '',

[image]

I need sort table with two states only asc/desc , Is it possible to customize.

Can any have idea on this.

Than in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set `matSortDisableClear` property on mat-table to disable the user from clearing the sort by finishing the sort direction cycle.

[reference](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api)

Comment: Perfect. This should be the default behavior. Im not sure what their reason is to have that default behavior where after descending and you click the sort again, the direction is empty.